# Apexcharts cannot use css variables as fill colors

Tags: css, apexcharts

I have tried several methods but no success at `fill colors`.

While I thought apexcharts couldn't use css variables as setting values, the following `stroke colors` work fine.

css

```
:root {
  --bs-warning: #ffc107;
}
```

js

```
var colors = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--bs-warning');
console.log(colors); // #ffc107

var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  fill: {
    colors: colors, // not working
    // or
    colors: '--bs-warning', // not working
    // or
    colors: 'var(--bs-warning)', // not working

    // but
    colors: '#ffc107', // Why this working???

    stroke: {
      colors: [colors], // hey, this working too but only within array! why?
    },
    // other config
    type: 'solid',
    opacity: 0.5,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too, and I've noticed something very important. The values received with .getPropertyValue() come in different formats on different devices. For example: Like '#RRGGBB' or '#RRGGBB' or 'RRGGBB' or 'RRGGBB'.

What surprised me the most here was that there was a space at the beginning of the returned color value on some devices. The function below will save you from all these troubles :)

```
let primaryColor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--bs-primary');

// Helper function to clean up color values
function cleanColor(color) {
    // remove any leading or trailing whitespace
    color = color.trim();
    // remove any leading # characters
    color = color.replace(/^#+/, '');
    // ensure the color string is exactly 6 characters long
    if (color.length < 6) {
        color = color.padStart(6, '0');
    } else if (color.length > 6) {
        color = color.slice(0, 6);
    }
    // add a leading # character
    color = '#' + color;
    return color;
}

// Clean up color values
primaryColor = cleanColor(primaryColor);
```

I hope it helps.